# Issue making method run at application launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, camera

I'm working on developing an app that uses the camera for a variety of different purposes. Right now, I'm struggling getting a tidbit of code to run when I launch the application:

```
UIImagePickerController *imageView = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
imageView.delegate = self;
imageView.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imageView.showsCameraControls = NO;

[self presentViewController:imageView animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I need this to execute on the `imageView` UIView object at launch so when the application is opened, it goes straight to `UIImagePickerController`. Here is all of my code for the application:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive
{

    UIImagePickerController *imageView = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imageView.delegate = self;
    imageView.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imageView.showsCameraControls = NO;

    [self presentViewController:imageView animated:YES completion:NULL];


}

@end
```

Comment: What's the actual problem? Where is the code you posted?

Comment: I edited my post so hopefully it's a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be informed in any controller, you should listen for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` or [similar notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-DontLinkElementID_4).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification 
                                               object:nil];
}
```

to unregister, do

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                              object:nil];
```

in `dealloc` or whenever you don't want to receive the notification anymore.

---

If you use storyboards, your app delegate should be like this

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

//…

@end
```

if you don't use storyboards your app delegate might be

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.window.rootViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    return YES;
}

//…

@end
```

and your view controller

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive
{

    UIImagePickerController *imageViewPickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imageViewPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentViewController:imageViewPickerController
                       animated:NO
                     completion:NULL];
}

@end
```

Comment: So, can I apply my code to this? I don't see how this enables me to have the `UIImagePickerController` to startup.

Comment: don't you see that your `applicationDidBecomeActive` is executed when the notification `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` is received?

Comment: ah, yes. so I place my code inside of the `applicationDidBecomeActive` in AppDelegate.m? That way when `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` is run, it will reference that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want code to run when you launch the app you should put it in:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

If you want the UIImagePickerController to be the first viewController presented you should set it as the window's rootViewController like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Set up imageView here

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.window.rootViewController = imageView;
    return YES;
}
```

Use presentViewController if/when you want to present it from another viewController that is already onscreen.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I feel like this is getting me really close, but I don't quite understand what a UIWindow object is. I gave it a google and I couldn't find any concise information. I don't quite understand the difference between a viewController and a UIWindow.

Comment: An application has one window, but can have many viewControllers. When you create a project in Xcode it should include code for the window in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, in the AppDelegate.m file. All you have to add is the line setting the rootViewController. You should probably read some documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html

Comment: please watch the WWDC 2011 video "implementing UIViewController containment." it explains a bit, why changing rootviewcontroller like this is a bad idea and actually the engineer warns several times "I promise you, bad things will happen". the least thing that will happen will be problems with orientation.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Yeah, his answer may not be the best for the question, but I was under the assumption that you thought it was not right to set the rootViewController ever.

Comment: Well, I suppose I should have been more clear. I really need to have my `UIImagePickerController` show up when the app is opened, and I was hoping to use storyboarding to make UI design a little bit easier. I know buttons and other UI elements can be created programmatically, but for this camera application a visual layout would be preferable.

Comment: @Nighthawk441: maybe trust the man with the golden objective-c badge (ok, I have to say, my first comments could had been more verbose). Even if there was just one UIViewController in the app and it was the root controller, it would be bad design to configure it like this in the app delegate. the apps delegate is meant to react on changes of the application state (background <-> foreground, active <-> inactive, incoming notifications). everything else should be done inside of view controllers. and cocoa makes it easy with those notifications that are broadcasted during star changes.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I tried placing my code inside of viewDidLoad and it didn't execute on launch.

Comment: @user3566222, is the view controller ever created? a object that doesn't exist cannot receive anything.

Comment: Yes, it definitely is. If I add a button or a label I can see it after I launch.